# Programming deontic logic

Tags: prolog, reasoning

I need to write rules for deontic logic, is there any programming language to do that? I saw prolog and I'm learning now but how to express deontic logic in PROLOG? please help

Comment: See this article about "[Deontic Action-Logic Multi-Agent Systems in Prolog](https://www.hig.se/download/18.5dd84b6d11f92f6598680001133/FoU+30+Hjelmblom.pdf)"... have [some code in git here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jdalmas/git/ci/master/tree/) (jDalmas).

Answer (score 1):

This paper from 2018 claims bridging deontic logic to SAT, for some ideas how this could be done see the 2015 paper:

A Deontic Logic Reasoning Infrastructure - 2018
Christoph Benzm¨uller, Xavier Parent, and Leendert van der Torre
http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/cbenzmueller/papers/C69.pdf

SMT-based BMC methods for standard Kripke structures
A.M. Zbrzezny - 2015
http://www.ifaamas.org/Proceedings/aamas2015/aamas/p2021.pdf

Many Prolog systems have SAT solvers. You could try something along
these lines. Here are some Prolog systems with SAT solvers:

SWI-Prolog CLP(B):
http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=clpb

Jekejeke Prolog CLP(B):
http://www.jekejeke.ch/idatab/doclet/prod/en/docs/15_min/10_docu/02_reference/07_theory/03_finite/06_tree.html